# Calculating $\int_{\mathcal{S}}x_1^r \, \mathrm dx_1\ldots \, \mathrm dx_n$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need help with the calculation of the following integral

$$
\int_{\mathcal{S}}x_1^r \, \mathrm dx_1\ldots  \, \mathrm dx_n
$$
where $r>0$ and
$$
\mathcal{S} = \left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n):a-\epsilon\leq x_1+\ldots+x_n\leq a,\;x_1\ldots,x_n\geq0\right\}
$$
for $a>0$ and $a-\epsilon>0$.

Thank you

Comment: Is $r$ an integer (otherwise you have to define $x_1^r$ for negative $x_1$)? Or maybe $\epsilon < a$?

Comment: @Fabian Right. See edit.

Comment: Do you also have $x_i>0$ ?

Comment: @Eckhard Yes I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$I = \int_{\mathcal{S}}x_1^r\,dx_1\ldots dx_n
 =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\lambda \int_{\mathcal{S}} \delta(\lambda-\sum_i x_i)  x_1^r\,d^n x
= \int_{a-\epsilon}^a d\lambda \int_{x_i\ge 0}\delta(\lambda-\sum_i x_i)  x_1^r\,d^nx. $$

Using the integral representation of the $\delta$-function (see Laplace transform)
$$\delta(\lambda-\sum_i x_i) = \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{ds}{2\pi i} e^{s(\lambda-\sum_i x_i)}$$
yields
$$\begin{align}I&=  \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{ds}{2\pi i} \int_{a-\epsilon}^a d\lambda\int_{x_i\ge 0} e^{s(\lambda-\sum_i x_i)} x_1^r\,d^nx\\
&= \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{ds}{2\pi i} \int_{a-\epsilon}^a d\lambda e^{s\lambda}
\int_0^\infty dx_1 x_1^r e^{-s x_1} \left(\int_0^\infty dx e^{-s x}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{ds}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{a s}-e^{s (a-\epsilon )}}{s} \frac{\Gamma(1+r)}{s^{r+1}}  \frac{1}{s^{n-1}}\\
&= \frac{\Gamma (r+1) \left(a^{n+r}-(a-\epsilon )^{n+r}\right)}{\Gamma (n+r+1)}.  \end{align}$$

Comment: Nice! Can't vote up (luck of reputation). Thank you

Comment: I tried to implement your "algorithm" to another "similar" integral. However, i'm afraid that it stuck with non-analytically integrals. Specifically, I want to calculate $\int_S(1-x_1^2)^rdx_1,...,dx_n$ where $S = (x_1,...,x_n):a-\epsilon<x_1+...+x_n<a, 1-x_i^2>0$. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user39097: not directly. I'm not sure if I understand all the constraints (are the $0<x_i<1$ or $|x_i|<1$?) In principle you can ask another question. Maybe with a reference to this question...

Comment: I meant $|x_i|<1$. You right. I will open a new post. Thanks