# Calculating of multi-dimensional integral 2

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need help with the calculation of the following integral

$$
\int_{\mathcal{S}}(1-x_1^2)^rdx_1\ldots dx_n
$$
where $r>0$ and
$$
\mathcal{S} = \left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n):a-\epsilon\leq x_1+\ldots+x_n\leq a,\;|x_i|\leq1 \;\;\forall i=1,\ldots,n\right\}
$$
for $\epsilon>0$.

This question apparently related to the answer of Fabian in [Calculating $\int_{\mathcal{S}}x_1^r \, \mathrm dx_1\ldots \, \mathrm dx_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264088/calculating-of-multi-dimensional-integral), however, in this case there are some non analytically integrals in the way...

Thank you

Comment: Can you expand $(1-x_1^2)^r$ using the (generalized) binomial theorem and apply the result from the other post?

Comment: You could implement the constraints on $x_i$ by hand, i.e., let the integral run from $-1$ to $1$ and use the method in the answer to the other question for the global constraint.

Comment: @Fabian I'm not sure that i'm exactly understand what you mean. Do you mean that I can use the same way just replacing the domain of integration from 0 to infinity to $-1$ to $1$? If so, this is what I tried to do, but, unfortunately it does not work (if i'm not wrong).

Comment: @Eckhard I am  not sure that it will help. The problem is with the domain of integration....

Comment: @Fabian I tried again, and I get integral of the form $\int_{-1}^1 e^{-sx}(1-x^2)^rdx$, which I can't solve. Can you please clarify what you meant in your previous comment?

Comment: Looks like a difficult integral. Maybe you can expand $(1-x^2)^r$ in a binomial series. I am not sure however if the integral over $s$ can be solve analytically in the end. But anyway better to have a single integral to do numerically than $n$ :-)

Comment: @Fabian That's for sure :)